# See all elements when Keyboard Open - Windows 10 Mobile - XAML - C#

Tags: c#, xaml, keyboard, scrollview, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a page and I have some doubts.
My project is for Windows 10 Mobile. On the page that I am developing, when a textbox has the focus, the mobile phone keyboard up and I get the rest of the hidden elements, and does not allow me to scroll will poara page to see all the elements.

Ja walked to do on the internet, but I saw that the solutions depend on ensuring greater size to my StackPanel than to my ScrolViewer but I do not need it as well.
  eg ScrollViewer Width = 500 ... StackPanel Width = 700

When the keypad on'd like to be able to see all the elements, making the scroll.

Follows my code:

```
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerTest VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,10">

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtUserNameMobile" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" 
                             Background="Black" Foreground="White"
                             PlaceholderText="Insert your text"
                             />

                    <Button x:Name="btnHere" 
                            Content="btnHere" 
                            Height="48"
                            Width="150">

                    <Button x:Name="btnHere2" 
                            Content="btnHere2" 
                            Height="48"
                            Width="150">

                    <Button x:Name="btnHere3" 
                            Content="btnHere3" 
                            Height="48"
                            Width="150">

                    <Button x:Name="btnHere4" 
                            Content="btnHere4" 
                            Height="48"
                            Width="150">

                     <Button x:Name="btnHere5" 
                            Content="btnHere5" 
                            Height="48"
                            Width="150">
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The default scrolling behavior of the page on `TextBox` focus can be overridden and custom logic can be added to show the focused `TextBox` when keyboard is shown. Using this method the `ScrollViewer` can be made to scroll when keyboard is open.

```
InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += InputPane_Showing;

private void InputPane_Showing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
        {
             args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true; //This will prevent the auto scroll of the page.
        }
```

`args.OccludedRect` will give the properties related to the keyboard like height, top position etc. These values can be used to move the `TextBox` to the required position if it is hidden behind the keyboard.

Comment: Hi @Bells. Not resolve my problema, but i just fixed this morning through the keyboard size, can make my scrollviwer and my grid had different size, subtracting the value from the keyboard which is visible.
Thanks anyway